# How do I send a notification from Parse to a Java application

Tags: java, iphone, rest, parse-platform

Does anybody who has experience with Parse.com servers know if a notification can be sent to a java application?

I want to be able to send data from the iphone to the computer, and I am using the REST API in java for the computer side of the application.  The problem is, the program does not know exactly when data will be sent.  Now, I know that I could send a query to Parse every second checking if there is any new data, but this would rack up a lot of API requests.  Is there some way I could have Parse notify my java application when new data is available?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android

Answer (score 0):

Parse JavaScript apps can't receive push notifications ([see](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript)).

In the past, I've been having the need to notify a JavaScript app. What I've implemented before is having the JS app checking on the server if new data is available every X amount of time. It's true that, for popular or demanding apps, this can build stack up a lot of API requests. However, my development team and I decided that, well, having 1 million API requests/mo (on the free tier), its not really that much.

Also, you could always [take a look at Background Jobs](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs), recently announced by Parse, to see if you can do something with them.